# Logging best approach with CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, design-patterns, logging, cdi

Creating a new version of my RESTful service architecture using JEE 7, deploying to a Wildfly 9 instance, I was wondering if there is a clever way to create a log system, can you suggest some patterns? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use [logback](http://logback.qos.ch) and regarding the patterns, well take a look at [logback layouts' documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) and create the one that fit your needs.

Answer (score 12):

I am using a simple producer with SLF4J interface for a JavaEE 7 JAX-RS project.

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LoggerProducer
{

    @Produces
    public Logger getLogger(final InjectionPoint ip)
    {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass());
    }
}
```

The usage is quite convenient by using injection.

```
@Inject
private Logger logger;
```

And the implementation can be changed easily without affecting any business classes. As the implementation slf4j-simple is sufficient for me, but if you need more advanced stuff, I would have a look at logback as already suggested or log4j 2.

Comment: Cool. thats the basic approach, I was thinking of something more advanced, maybe using the observer pattern, but dont know if that would'nt be over engineering

Comment: Personally I try to keep things as simple as possible (KIS). Can you please point out what are the limitations for you that you need something more advanced?